# Get total of all columns which have agree data in them

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working in SQL server and doing analysis on some data. Below is the picture of my data which consists of 46 columns. In picture not all the columns are being shown but I hope you are getting the idea of how it is.
All the columns have "agree" "disagree" or "agree to some extent" data in them.
[image]

Now I want to get the total of "agree" row by row of all the columns. The new column totalagree will have the value of how many agree are there in a row in every column. Is there any SQL query which can help me achieve this task.

Comment: Blargh... I think the better answer here is to reconsider your data structure. Building your data structure like that is very rarely a good idea. Is that something you'd be happy to take into consideration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is a giant `case` expression:

```
select . . .,
       ( (case when col1 = 'agree' then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when col2 = 'agree' then 1 else 0 end) +
         . . . 
       ) as total_agree
```

If you have more such columns that you want to calculate, then you can unpivot the data and re-aggregate:

```
select t.*, total_agree
from t cross apply
     (select count(*) as total_agree
      from (values ('col1', col1), ('col2', col2), . . .
           ) v(which, val)
      where val = 'agree'
     ) v;
```

Finally, you have a poor data model.  The reason the queries are relatively complicated is because you have data in separate columns that should be in separate rows.  You should have a table with one row per entity and one per "lesson plan".  The queries would be simpler.